# Threejs: Terrain texture happens invisible/transparent

Tags: three.js, textures, webgl, terrain, texturing

Three.js **r62**

I have a scene from .obj file with a few meshes. 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8913924/terrain/index.html

I try to apply a texture to the "terrain" object.
Result is an invisible/transparent texture.

(if a texture applied to any other objects in the scene - everything seems ok)

**check the demo above**.

Notes:
.mtl file is empty;

Upload a texture  and apply the one to all the objects of the scene:

```
/* prepare the texture */
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'crate.gif' );
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Apply this texture to terrain and all other objects:

```
if ( ('string' == typeof o.type) && ( 'terrain' == o.type)){
 /*work with terrain*/          
 //object.children[i].material = object.children[i].material.clone();
 object.children[i] = new THREE.Mesh (object.children[i].geometry.clone(), object.children[i].material.clone());
 object.children[i].material.color.setHex(0xffffff);
 object.children[i].material.map = texture;
 object.children[i].material.ownMaterial = true;
 //console.log('terrain colored');
} else  {
      /*work with all other objects*/
  object.children[i].material = object.children[i].material.clone();
  object.children[i].material.ownMaterial = true;
  object.children[i].material.map = texture;                    
}
```

Comment: The texture is not invisible. You have console errors because your terrain geometry does not have UVs.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't see any related erors. Should I set UVs programatically or can i set UVs in my model somehow ?

Comment: You need to learn how to identify errors in the Console... Most likely, UVs would already be present in your model.

Comment: Thanks for your hints and attention.